# display a screen 4 seconds after another one

Tags: react-native, screen, loading

I would like to know how in my App.js file to display my "welcome" screen for 4 seconds then go to my classic 'AppNavigator' navigation screens. For now I just return AppNavigator, and in fact I would have liked to open the app with a nice page including my client's logo.
Could you guide me to do this? Thank you.
For now, I just have :

```
export default function App() {
  return (
  <AppNavigation />
  );
}
```

Comment: This is a snack that i made for a blogpost which will cover your requirement and other basic scenarios, you can check it out https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/rnn-v5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean a splash screen. Try https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/

Otherwise, you could start with your 'welcome' view and navigate or update your state after x seconds using a timeout. `setTimeout(() => action(), seconds * 1000)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've missed the name of the splashscreen. As I use a function component I've used the answer of @ Guruparan Giritharan but it helps thank you :)